# What is actual purpose of .thrift file in an Apache Thrift based application?

Tags: distributed, thrift

Does the `.thrift` file reside in the Server side or the client side of the application?

What is actual purpose of `.thrift` file in an Apache Thrift based application?

Is it only used for generating minimal source codes for the application, or, does it have any other use?

Can't I just write client-server codes myself without taking the help of `.thrift` file?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C# specifically.  Removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.thrift` file is an IDL file, where IDL stands for [Interface description language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language). The main purpose of this file is to generate the service-specific code for the desired target language(s). The like any other IDL file, the `*.thrift` IDL file **is not required to be copied onto server or client end to have a working solution**.

Aside from that, making the IDL file publicly available [can be useful for documentation purposes](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-thrift) for developers that want to use the service.