# How to process data on HDFS with .thrift?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs, thrift

I have a .thrift file (Generating Java job) on HDFS as below:

```
/**
* Contains thrift object definition for ABstudy holdback
**/
namespace java com.TK101.ads.study.gen
#@namespace scala com.TK101.ads.ABstudy.thriftscala

/**
* Different types of hold back
*/
enum Bucket {
  HOLDBACK_TARGETED,
  HOLDBACK_GENERAL_RECRUITMENT,
  HOLDBACK_POST_AUCTION,
  EXPOSED,
  UNEXPOSED_AUCTIONLOST,
  UNEXPOSED_FILTERED,
}

/**
* Contains the information on user holdbacks
*/
struct ABStudy {
  1: optional i64 holdbackUserId;
  2: optional i64 holdbackAdvertiserId;
  3: optional i64 holdbackCampaignId;
  4: optional Bucket holdbackType;
  5: optional i64 holdbackTimeMilliSecs;
  6: optional i64 creativeId;
}
```

I want to use this .thrift file to generate job to process data on another directory of HDFS. How can I execute the .thrift file on the data?

Comment: This is just the definition of the data structures. You can't "generate a job" from it. Have to actually write the code ... You can generate the scala/java classes for the data structure it defines using a thrift compiler: https://thrift.apache.org/ If you are working with scala only, then scrooge may be a better option: http://twitter.github.io/scrooge/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is actual purpose of .thrift file in an Apache Thrift based application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732446/what-is-actual-purpose-of-thrift-file-in-an-apache-thrift-based-application)